# 時間を正しく表示させたい。

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

時間の表記が明らかにおかしいのですが、どうすれば治るのかが分かりません。

```
function myFunction() {
  let year = new Date().getFullYear();
  const startDate = new Date("2020/4/1 12:00");
  console.log(startDate);  
  console.log(startDate.getUTCMonth());
  console.log(startDate.getUTCFullYear());
  console.log(exchangeTIME(startDate));
}
function exchangeTIME(startDate) {
  const startDATE =
    startDate.getUTCFullYear() + ("0" + (startDate.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
    ("0" + startDate.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) + 'T' + ("0" + startDate.getUTCHours()).slice(-2) +
    ("0" + startDate.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2) + ("0" + startDate.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2);

  return startDATE;
}
```

> [20-06-05 15:52:09:485 JST] Wed Apr 01 2020 12:00:00 GMT+0900 (日本標準時)
>   [20-06-05 15:52:09:487 JST] 3
>   [20-06-05 15:52:09:489 JST] 2020
>   [20-06-05 15:52:09:491 JST] 20200401T030000

となり、時間がおかしく出力されるのです。「T030000」が本来であれば、「T120000」となるはずです。どうすれば、時間を表示することが出来ますか？

GASの環境下で実行しています。

Answer (score 0):

getUTCXXX系のメソッドを利用していますが
これらのメソッドは
協定世界時
を出力するためのものです。

もしブラウザや処理系のローカル時間を使いたいのであれば
getXXX系のメソッドを使うようにしましょう

getUTCMonth
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMonth

getMonth
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Comment: gasなのでローカルではないと思いますが。一応、変えて実行しましたが、まったく変わりませんでした。

Comment: @asdfe GASの場合でもタイムゾーンはUTCとは限りません（スプレッドシートなどの設定に依存）。getHoursを使っても結果が同じなのは不思議ですが…

Comment: Javasciptの実行環境＝ローカルという表現です。サーバで実行すればサーバのtimezoneの設定、ブラウザで実行すればブラウザのtimezoneの設定。GASであればそれぞれの実行環境での設定によるとは思います。質問の意図としてはローカルの時間ではなくて、JSTを使いたいということですかね？